# Order of events in asp classic when generating excel spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, forms, excel, asp-classic

Long time Lurker...

Short story long:  I'm building some on-the-fly spreadsheets with asp classic and MS SQL.  I'll simplfy this to the basics since my issue isn't in creating the spreadsheets or building the forms.  The issue is what happens AFTER the spreadsheets are created.

User specifies the variables, order by vars, display type (radio buttons, check boxes, text areas, drop downs, javascript form checking, and all that jazz) .

Submission goes to an assembly asp classic page, grabs stuff out of the database, then EITHER displays to screen OR uses AddHeader (both using various include files/SQL views) to bodge it all into an excel spreadsheet and ship the file off to the user.

ISSUE:  When the spreadsheet option is specified, the user experience is to have the form (with all of their choices) remain in the browser.  After opening (or saving) the spreadsheet file - the user returns to their browser to find the form as exactly they left it.

NOT A PROBLEM for me... but the client??? Loves how everything works EXCEPT **they want the form reset** to the starting position.

I have looked at (and tried over the past 10 hours) just about everything (from javascript pop-under windows to response.redirects) and I am STUCK on where to intervene in this process.

The client does NOT want the html reports to open in a new window and doesn't want a separate form-set for screen viewing vs spreadsheets. So I am kind of limited in approach.

So somehow I need to find a way to determine that the spreadsheet has completed or the form has been submitted in spreadsheet mode and then refresh the page the form is on.... sigh.

Ideas?????  Clues???

Comment: I understand you've been a long time lurker, but can you please try to boil down this wall of text into just the important information? Simply explain what the problem is, and any associated error messages or problems. We don't need a lot of the extra context you provide here.

Comment: Why don't you just clear the form after it's been submitted? Either use an `onsubmit` handler or if you're submitted via a function then add it in there.

Answer (score 0):

This [jQuery plugin](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) gives you success and failure callbacks when downloading a file.

So in the success callback you could execute some JavaScript to reset the form, and in the fail callback display a friendly error message if something went wrong.

Comment: I ended up following Tim's advice-took the long road and unset all form elements after any spreadsheet onClick event. Annoying but it worked :-P